# Bootstrap - Select all checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have the following HTML structure using bootstrap. I need to select a checkbox to select all the checkboxes but the javascript codes I've been testing have not worked (I'm not very good at javascript). I think these codes do not work because they do not take into account the "active" class that uses bootstrap.

The following javascript not worked for me:

```
    <script>
    function toggle(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i] != source)
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Test

```
    <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>EXAMPLE</legend>
            <div class="form-group rowauto" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label for="selectall">SELECT/UNSELECT ALL:</label>
                <label class="btn btn-success active checkboxkox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" name="selectall" autocomplete="off" checked>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="row rowauto">
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <div class="form-group rowauto" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-success active checkboxkox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="check_1" name="check_1" autocomplete="off" checked>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row rowauto">
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <div class="form-group rowauto" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-success active checkboxkox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="check_2" name="check_2" autocomplete="off" checked>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

The IDs of my checkboxs are generated by a loop "foreach" in PHP

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant JavaScript code** that you have tried, showcasing the **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 6):

Trying to use your Html, you can add the event `onclick` in the checkbox to select/unselect all checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall" name="selectall" autocomplete="off" checked onclick="eventCheckBox()">
```

And use the property `checked` in your javascript:

```
function eventCheckBox() {
  let checkbox1 = document.getElementById("check_1");
  checkbox1.checked = !checkbox1.checked;
  
  let checkbox2 = document.getElementById("check_2");
  checkbox2.checked = !checkbox2.checked;
}
```

[JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln6gt54a/)

**Update:**

To not depend of the id name, you can use:

```
function eventCheckBox() {
  let checkboxs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(let i = 0; i < checkboxs.length ; i++) { //zero-based array
    checkboxs[i].checked = !checkboxs[i].checked;
  }
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln6gt54a/1/)

Comment: It maybe work but, the IDs of my checkboxs are generated by a loop "foreach" in PHP.

Comment: @JorgeAguilar, yes but if you make a little more effort you can change my code for your necesity and so learn more, anyway I updated my code that not depend of the id, if you have more restrictions try to first make a attempt and if you have a problem, ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" name="selectall" autocomplete="off" checked>
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall" name="selectall" onclick="toggle(this)" autocomplete="off" checked>
```

and

```
 function toggle(source) {
```

to

```
toggle = function(source) {
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6d0kmv0/1/)

Comment: I have tried this code and it works when I do not use the bootstrap.
But when I use the bootstrap it stops working and I think it's because Bootstrap dynamically adds the "active" class to the label enclosing the input of the checkbox.
That is, when a checkbox is activated, bootstrap adds the "active" class to add the check.